# Chrome session times out and breaks the page. Issue only with Chrome and working in other browsers

Tags: google-chrome, session, redirect, browser

We have a webpage which redirects user to third party and returns him back, after transaction, to our domain.
In Chrome, during this journey, session changes and breaks the page after returning, due to previous missing session-values. New session id gets created and is happening only in Chrome. But it is working fine in other browsers.

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: Issue happens in Chrome and is not happening everytime. We supsected it is timing out in less than a minute but it happens suddenly at some point of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding SameSite cookie attribute to None for JSESSIONID cookie resolved the issue